# Magento 2 Detect Maintenance mode

Tags: magento-2.1, maintenance

I'm actually trying to find a function which has to detect if the website is in maintenance mode or not do someone have the answer please? I know we can do it in the Console but I need it in one of my bloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to detect this inside of one of your classes.
You need to add this dependency to it `Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode`.

Make your class constructor look like this:

```
protected $maintenanceMode;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode $maintenanceMode,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->maintenanceMode = $maintenanceMode;
    ....
}
```

Then you can call inside of your class this:

```
$flag = $this->maintenanceMode->isOn();
```

you can even specify an ip address as parameter for `isOn`

Answer (score 0):

If you find **var/.maintenance.flag** file then your Magento 2 store is in maintenance mode. It is hidden file so you may need to turn on show hidden files.

Comment: so i need to use the file_exists but i'm quite new in Magento is that possible to made a function in my module which go search out of the module ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento detects maintenance mode as follows:

1. If var/.maintenance.flag does not exist, maintenance mode is off and
   Magento operates normally.
2. Otherwise, maintenance mode is on unless var/.maintenance.ip exists

**Command usage:**

```
magento maintenance:enable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]
magento maintenance:disable [--ip=<ip address> ... --ip=<ip address>] | [ip=none]
magento maintenance:status
```

Answer (score 0):

When Maintenance Mode is enabled Magento creates a flag file in `var/.maintenance.flag`

Check this file

```
vendor/magento/framework/App/MaintenanceMode.php
```

function

```
/**
 * Sets maintenance mode "on" or "off"
 *
 * @param bool $isOn
 * @return bool
 */
public function set($isOn)
{
    if ($isOn) {
        return $this->flagDir->touch(self::FLAG_FILENAME);
    }
    if ($this->flagDir->isExist(self::FLAG_FILENAME)) {
        return $this->flagDir->delete(self::FLAG_FILENAME);
    }
    return true;
}
```

To Check if maintenance mode is enabled check this function

```
/**
 * Checks whether mode is on
 *
 * Optionally specify an IP-address to compare against the white list
 *
 * @param string $remoteAddr
 * @return bool
 */
public function isOn($remoteAddr = '')
{
    if (!$this->flagDir->isExist(self::FLAG_FILENAME)) {
        return false;
    }
    $info = $this->getAddressInfo();
    return !in_array($remoteAddr, $info);
}
```